# In-App purchase Testing Help IAP

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

This is my first IAP. I am having problems testing if the IAP works.  Every guide & or tutorial has not solved my issues.  My iOS code calls IAP, but does not return any products... The identifier is correct.

On iTunesConnect the IAP (which is to remove ads) says "Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit."

This does not make any sense, I have already gone to my app details and added the IAP there, still testing it does not work.

Does this mean i need to submit my app to the app-store before i can even test my IAP? I dont understand... I have already tried uploading a new version of my app to iTunes.

Also in iTUnes connect it says Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit.
Once your binary has been uploaded and your first In-App Purchase has been submitted for review, additional In-App Purchases can be submitted using the table below." and also the status is "ready to submit", however when i click on it the "submit for review" button is greyed out in the top right

Comment: You asked: "Does this mean i need to submit my app to the app-store before i can even test my IAP?" Is the answer a "Yes"? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: You should not upload a screenshot yet.  First test your IAP, then once ready for app submission upload a screenshot.  This is surprisingly not documented very well.